# What happens on an interrupt when guest is under execution?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, intel, kvm

My question is regarding interrupts and how are they handed when the guest is executing in KVM?

Lets say when kvm calls vmentry or vmresume, the guest code starts executing. Now when an external interrupt say timer interrupt occurs, the guest will cause a vmexit. After Vmexit will the next instruction in kvm execute or will the host interrupt caller gets called. If the next instruction in kvm gets called then kvm can do whatever it wants to and then call the appropriate host interrupt handler.

Thanks,

Comment: It will always run under the kernel process, why should userspace processes or rights have anything to with kernel space?

Answer (score 3):

On Intel VT-x, all interrupts cause a trap into the host operating system. The host will then determine if the interrupt is:

- For itself (in which case it will handle it, possibly causing KVM to sit unscheduled for quite some time); or
- For the guest, in which case it will inform KVM about the interrupt. KVM will then, in turn, inject the interrupt into the guest. (Note that this part of KVM runs in kernel mode; but I presume that you would still consider this to be KVM).

In either case, the host operating system takes control first.

Somewhat unrelated, but one extension to VT-x that would make us virtualisation guys happier is if certain interrupts could be sent directly to the guest, avoiding the trap into the host (and associated performance penalty) altogether. Alas, this doesn't seem to be on the cards just yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding ur second point, I think it possibly is done when there is a passthru device. Since the host does not know about it, guest interrupt handler will be called always.

Comment: Currently on VT-x all interrupts trap into the host, which must forward them to the guest if appropriate. This causes real performance problems, unfortunately, and hopefully will be improved by Intel in a later revision of VT-x.

Comment: Re: your suggested improvement, what would happen if the guest wasn't currently running when the interrupt arrived?

Comment: If the guest wasn't running, you would still take the trap into the host; further interrupts would be masked until the guest was next scheduled (and the interrupts dealt with). When the guest was running, however, you would avoid these extraneous traps and get a performance boost.

Comment: With APIC enabled, is it less likely to be a guest interrupt?

Comment: The extension described—allowing interrupt delivery directly to a currently running guest vcpu—was implemented as a feature called "posted interrupts" about 6 years after this was written.