# what happens when an external interrupt is received by the host in a virtual setting

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, virtualization, kvm

I'm trying to understand what happens in a virtualization setting when the host receives an external interrupt. For example if `CPU-1` is being utilized by `vCPU-0` of a VM and there is an external interrupt, can that host ISR run on `CPU-1` or does it prevent all host interrupts from running on CPU's assigned to the VM ? If it can, then does it result in a `VMExit` and if so how does one go from host ISR running to VMExit ? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860785/what-happens-on-an-interrupt-when-guest-is-under-execution) addresses part of it but does not discuss the path I'm mention above, it assumes a VMExit happens but I'm looking for the sequence of steps that lead to it.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU that the interrupt is delivered to is controlled by the interrupt remapping table in the IOMMU and/or the MSI programmed in the device.

When the interrupt is delivered to the CPU core, it generally causes a VM exit. The VM exit is caused by the interrupt itself, before any interrupt handler is called.

It is up to the VM exit handler to decide how to handle the interrupt and whether a host ISR should be called.

The VT-d feature called posted interrupts allows an interrupt to be delivered directly to the currently running VCPU without a VM exit, as described in the answer to the question you linked.

Comment: Thanks @prl. So the guest receiving an interrupt is along the same lines as the guest trapping on special instructions e.g. io with the exit reason being an external interrupt?